# Nginx 403 access forbidden when using X-Accel-Redirect

Tags: nginx

I have an issue in Nginx with security and `X-Accel-Redirect`.

**Nginx Server 777**

```
location /api {
   allow 100.100.100.1;
   deny all;
   proxy_pass http://api-server;
}

#The api-sever will respond with an `X-Accel-Redirect` header to the following location `@server888`

location @server888 {
   internal;
   proxy_pass http://server888$request_uri;
}
```

**Nginx Server 888** has identical config for `/api`

```
location /api {
   allow 100.100.100.1;
   deny all;
   proxy_pass http://api-server;
}
```

However, all requests from source ip `100.100.100.1` to **Server 777** are getting a 403 response from **Server 777**, with the error:

```
access forbidden by rule while reading response header from upstream
```

From what I can see, the `@server888` location is blocking the request, but my understanding is that the `internal` directive should allow requests originating from `X-Accel-Redirect`, without having to provide an explicit `allow` directive for `100.100.100.1`.

Is this correct? Or do I need to grant more extensive permissions in the `@server888` location for this to work?

Comment: Is it possible that you have one of those host names mapped to an ipv6 address in one of those server's hosts file? If so, the remote web server might be lacking right vhost configuration for ipv6. So depending on how the default vhost is configured on the remote server you might get a 403 forbidden instead of your desired backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like the custom `location` (@server888) needs to permit the loopback address in order for this to work:

```
location @server888 {
   allow 127.0.0.1;
   internal;
   proxy_pass http://server888$request_uri;
}
```

I'm not sure what the technical explanation is here.

Normally, the `internal` directive should permit access when the request is generated by `X-Accel-Redirect`:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal

My guess here is that this only applies when the `location` is local, rather than a reverse proxy to an upstream, or that this location is inheriting a more global `deny all;` earlier in the config.